# Powershell : How to Add Clickable Text in a WPF RitchTextBox?

Tags: wpf, powershell, hyperlink, richtextbox, clickable

I have a problem in using the RichTextBox for a WPF in Powershell.

I'm loading a file.txt that have is own meta inside and i get this meta to underline / bold .... the classic text formatting.

One of this meta is **Link** so i want to make the values clickable in my Richtextbox

> @{" Amiforce-Distribution (important!) " link "amiforce"}

The Links autodetection in RichTextBox only working double \ and "http" like texts.

**Question :**
Is there a way please to "AppendText" that is clickable and which is captured by the event handler $RichTextBox_LinkClicked = [System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventHandler]{} ?

I checked all the urls i found on google about this subject but all are for C# and i found nothing usefull for my Powershell :)

La meilleur piste que j'ai trouvé consiste à créer un objet linklabel et d'essayer de l'appendtext dans ma richtextbox mais cela ne marche pas :

```
$Textlink = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$Textlink.text = "AMIGA"
$Richtextbox.AppendText("$Textlink `n")
```

Mais cela ne marche pas chez moi.

Pour mémoire voici les propriétées de l'objet LinkLabel

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Help Please Help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it after more research, i hope it will help peoples

```
$Textlink = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$Textlink.text = "AMIGA"
$Textlink.Name = "AMIGALINK"
$Textlink.Location = $MainTextBoxOutput.GetPositionFromCharIndex($MainTextBoxOutput.TextLength)
$richtextbox.AppendText("$Textlink.text `n")
$richtextbox.Controls.Add($Textlink)
$richtextbox.SelectionStart = $richtextbox.TextLength
```

Best regards,

AMIGA Rulez